# How to overwrite the file

Tags: regex, perl

I try to learn Perl and have some problems. I tried to overwrite the original file but It didn't work. Please, help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use diagnostics;
use warnings;
use strict;

open (FILE, '>>apple.txt');
while (<FILE>){      
    s/is/at/;    # Substitute 'is' for 'at'
    print FILE;
    close (FILE);   
}
```

I tried to change all `is` to `at` and to write the result into the original file.

Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Provide more information on what goes wrong, how. I.e. provide current result in comparison to desired result.

Comment: You probably want the `/g` modifier. And you also want to open your file for reading. You opened it in append writing mode `>>`. What kind of tutorial or book are you using?

Comment: @simbabque I just found some tutorials in the internet. I used to read the book but it wasn´t useful to me.

Comment: Which tutorial? Please give me a link.

Comment: @simbabque From this site https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/Perl2_Regexe.html

Comment: Well, it's not the most current, but it looks fine. Search in the page for `FileChange.pl`. That shows how to open two different file handles, read from one and write to the other.

Comment: @simbabque OK. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to spend any amount of time programming in Perl, then it will be well worth taking the time to read through the [Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html). One of the questions answered in section 4 seems useful here.

[How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2C-delete%2C-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2C-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3F)

The answer starts like this:

> The basic idea of inserting, changing, or deleting a line from a text
>   file involves reading and printing the file to the point you want to
>   make the change, making the change, then reading and printing the rest
>   of the file. Perl doesn't provide random access to lines (especially
>   since the record input separator, `$/`, is mutable), although modules
>   such as [Tie::File](https://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) can fake it.
>
> A Perl program to do these tasks takes the basic form of opening a file,
>   printing its lines, then closing the
>   file:
>
> ```
>    open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
>    open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";
>    while( <$in> ) {
>         print $out $_;
>    }
>    close $out;
> ```

A few comments on your current code:

- You don't need both `-w` and `use warnings`. Most people just use the latter.
- Please use the three-argument version of `open()` and lexical filehandles - `open my $file_handle, '>>', 'apple.txt'`.
- You should always check the return value from `open()` and take appropriate action. Often people use `die()` for this - `open my $file_handle, '>>', 'apple.txt' or die "Can't open file: $!`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl generally does not support direct access to files.
It is preferred to write the changed content to a temporary file,
close both input and output files and rename the temporary file to the input.

Or if this is **the only thing** you want to do, you can use
a *one-liner* command like:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/is/at/" -- apple.txt
```

which does roughly the same.

Or if you **very much** want to program this operation
on your own, then:

- visit *perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html* page,
- find description of `-i[extension]` option,
- after words *which is equivalent to* you will find the equivalent Perl code.

And a remark concerning your code:

```
open (FILE, '>>apple.txt');
```

opens the file with the current position pointer **at the end of the file**,
so any *print* command **adds** the text, instead of overwriting the file
from the start.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named `Tie::File` can do the request might be:

```
use Tie::File;

my $inputFile = "test.txt";

my @array = ();
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $inputFile || die "Error: Couldn't tie the \"$inputFile\" file: $!";
my $len = join "\n", @array;

if($len=~m/is/) {  $len=~s/is/at/g;  }

@array = split/\n/, $len;
untie @array;
```